# Grid filter with textfield extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, grid

Does anyone help me? I've created a grid and add filter on a outside textfield, on one filter it runs but when I add textfield it doesn't run, when the first textfield is blur, the filter doesn't run. bellow is my code:

```
filterGrid = function (property, value) {
    var grid = Ext.getCmp('grid');
    grid.store.clearFilter();
    if (value) {
        var matcher = new RegExp(Ext.String.escapeRegex(value), "i");
        grid.store.filter({
            filterFn: function (record) {
                return matcher.test(record.get(property));
            }
        });
    }
};

var grid = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'border',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    height: 500,
    items: [{
            xtype: 'form',
            region: 'north',
            id: 'formPanel',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            height: 75,
            collapsible: true,
            layout: 'hbox',
            items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Name',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    id: 'name',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, value) {
                            filterGrid('name', value);
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Email',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    id: 'email',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, value) {
                            filterGrid('email', value);
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Phone',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    id: 'phone',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, value) {
                            filterGrid('phone', value);
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Type',
                    labelAlign: 'right',
                    id: 'type',
                    listeners: {
                        change: function (field, value) {
                            filterGrid('type', value);
                        }
                    }
                }]
        },
        {
            xtype: 'grid',
            region: 'center',
            searchValue: null,
            matches: [],
            currentIndex: null,
            searchRegExp: null,
            caseSensitive: false,
            regExpMode: false,
            matchCls: 'x-livesearch-match',
            defaultStatusText: 'Nothing Found',
            id: 'grid',
            store: {
                fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone', 'type'],
                data: [{
                        name: 'Homer',
                        email: 'homer@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '111-222-333',
                        type: 'Foo'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Marge',
                        email: 'marge@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '111-222-334',
                        type: 'Foo'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Bart',
                        email: 'bart@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '111-221-335',
                        type: 'Bar'
                    }, {
                        name: 'Lisa',
                        email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                        phone: '111-221-336',
                        type: 'Bar'
                    }]
            },
            columnLines: true,
            columns: [{
                    text: 'Name',
                    dataIndex: 'name',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'email',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Phone',
                    dataIndex: 'phone',
                    flex: 1
                }, {
                    text: 'Type',
                    dataIndex: 'type',
                    flex: 1
                }],
      }]
});
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

In the filterGrid function, you are clearing all filters using `grid.store.clearFilter();` and then creating a single filter for the property that corresponds to the textfield that was changed.  This means there will only be a single filter applied to the store at any time.

One way to approach this would be to remove only the filter that was applied for a particular property instead of clearing all filters.  Then you can add (or re-add) a filter for the changed property.  To do this you need to identify the filters.  For example: `grid.store.filters.getAt(grid.store.filters.length-1).property=property;` would tag each filter with the name of the property that was used to create it.  This would enable you to remove the specific filter using

```
grid.store.filters.each(function(item) {
    if (item.property === property) {
        grid.store.removeFilter(item);
    }  
})
```

and then add the filter using

```
grid.store.addFilter({
    filterFn: function (record) {
        return matcher.test(record.get(property));
    }
});
```

See fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k74